# How can I disable buttons except to the button I click?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a table inside the modal. When the user clicks the button 'Show Modal' the modal will show. I'm trying to disable all the button except the button I click which become green when clicked. I want the green button named 'Selected' remains to enable and the rest of the red button named 'Select' is disabled. How can I do that? Can somebody help me with my problem? Here's my jsfiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/gLbwe8fy/1/

```
   makeBeneficiaryButton : function(id, index) {
            if(event.target.innerText == "Select") {
                event.target.innerText = "Selected";
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                $("#myModal11").find('button#select').prop('disabled', 'disabled'); 
            }
            else {
                event.target.innerText = "Select";
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#cc0000";
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using plain js code which is not a problem but I'm going to give you a solution more `vuejs` oriented.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data : {
        dependents: [{
          dependent_id : 1,
          dependent_first_name : "John",
          dependent_middle_name : "Denver",
          dependent_last_name : "Doe",
          dependent_address : "USA",
          dependent_contact_no : "431-431-431"
        },
        {
          dependent_id : 2,
          dependent_first_name : "John",
          dependent_middle_name : "Denver",
          dependent_last_name : "Doe",
          dependent_address : "USA",
          dependent_contact_no : "431-431-431"
        },
        {
          dependent_id : 3,
          dependent_first_name : "John",
          dependent_middle_name : "Denver",
          dependent_last_name : "Doe",
          dependent_address : "USA",
          dependent_contact_no : "431-431-431"
        }],
      selected: null
  },
  methods : {
     isDisabled (index) {
       if (this.selected === null) return false;
        return index != this.selected;
      },
      innerText (index) {
       if (index === this.selected) return 'selected';
        return 'select';
      },
      backgroundColor (index) {
       if (index === this.selected) return "background-color: green";
        return "background-color: #cc0000";
      },
   makeBeneficiaryButton : function(index) {
        this.selected = this.selected === null ? this.selected = index : null;
   }
  }
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="vue-app">
  <button class="btn bg-success btn-sm text-light" href="#add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal11">Show Modal</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal11" class="text-dark" tabindex="1"> <!-- start update modal -->
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content">
        
       <!-- Modal Header -->
       <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
       </div>
           
       <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-medicine">
           <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-hover table-bordered text-center mt-2">
      <thead class="thead-info">
                <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>Full Name</th >
                 <th>Address</th>
                 <th>Contact No</th>
                 <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
                  <tbody v-if="dependents.length > 0">
                   <tr v-for="(dependent, index) in dependents">
                    <td>{{dependent.dependent_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{dependent.dependent_first_name +  " " + dependent.dependent_middle_name + " " + dependent.dependent_last_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{dependent.dependent_address}}</td>
                    <td>{{dependent.dependent_contact_no}}</td>
                    <td>
                     <button :id="index" @click="makeBeneficiaryButton(index)"  :style="backgroundColor(index)" class="btn btn-sm text-light" class="btn bg-success btn-sm" :disabled="isDisabled(index)">{{ innerText(index) }}</button>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tbody v-else>
                   <tr>
        <td colspan="12" style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center"><b>No dependent to show</b></td>
       </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
         <i class="far fa-save">&nbsp;</i> Save
        </button>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- update modal end -->
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```